# C# WPF Linq Join 4 tables and Where with varying parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, linq

I want to work with Linq to create a Join with four tables. The second "bigger" problem is, that for the `.Where(...)` I have parameters. But not constantly the same parameters. They can change from min 2 to max 7 or 8.
There are 7 or 8 TextFields or Comboboxes and they should all be used for "filtering". E.g. i can only fill two for my Linq-Method or all of them. So i have round about 49 possibilities for different Linq-Selects and I´m not really a big fan of coding them all. So is there a possibilty that `.Where(...)` automatically ignores parameters with no value?

```
public static ZeichnungCollection findDrawings(int projektID, string zeichnungsnummer, int tagID, string status, string mmsSachmerkmal, string doktyp, string dateiendung, int volIndex)
{
   ZeichnungCollection zeichnungen = new ZeichnungCollection();
   ZeichnungInDB zeichnungInDB;
   using (var context = new DMSContext())
     {
       var query =
       from z in context.zeichnungs
       where z.Zeichnungsnummer == zeichnungsnummer && z.Projekt_ID == projektID
       select z;
       if(query != null)
       {
         foreach (zeichnung zeichnung in query)
         {
           zeichnungInDB = new ZeichnungInDB(zeichnung.Dateiname_Org, zeichnung.Zeichnungsnummer, zeichnung.Index, zeichnung.Dateiendung,
           zeichnung.Aenderung_Ext, zeichnung.Aenderung_Int, zeichnung.Aenderung_Bemerkung_Txt, zeichnung.Ahang_Link, zeichnung.Dokumententyp,
           zeichnung.Status, zeichnung.Zeitstempel, zeichnung.Einzel_Bemerkung_Txt, zeichnung.Einzel_Link, zeichnung.Volante_Index,
           zeichnung.MMS_Sachmerkmal, zeichnung.ID, zeichnung.Baugruppe_ID, zeichnung.Projekt_ID, zeichnung.Tag_ID);
           zeichnungen.Add(zeichnungInDB);
          }
       }
     }
     return zeichnungen;
}
```

The code is at the moment without a Join because I´m not quite sure if I really need all the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, for example, do like:

```
where (textField1Value == "" || textField1Value == attribute1) && (textField2Value == "" || textField2Value == attribute2) && (textField3Value == "" || textField3Value == attribute3)
```

Comment: Ok. So the first two TextFields i need every time the others are optional. Can I use this for any constitution, don´t matter what Fields I filled something in?

Comment: If textField1Value is empty, then textField1Value == "" returns true, else (if it is not empty), then textField1Value == attribute1 is evaluated... If your empty value is something other than the empty string "", then use that value in its place...

Comment: Note the use of &&: this means all the available field values must match to return a result. If not you can use ||

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems it was to simple that I found an answer for myself.